# how to read cookies for multiliple membership in php

Tags: php, cookies

**hello,**

how can i set cookies like 'last_visit' if the user have more than one account on my site
i tried some methods but i failed.

that`s the code when the user log out

```
setcookie('last_visit',time(),time()+60*60*24*30*12);
```

but when the user relogin with another account the page read the last visit of his first account with this code

```
  $lastvisit = $_COOKIE['last_visit'];
```

can i link the last visit cookie with the user id cookie in one cookie

**please help me with the right method**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove existing or old cookies when writing new ones. Do a mutually exclusive login, when people log in to one account they are sign-out from the others.

Comment: yes i knew that, but when users sign-out the website removes their cookies like user_name user_id by putting a NULL value because this cookies has values when they logged in but lastvisit must have value when they leave that`s the difference. so now i have value for last visit and when user login with another account the website will read the the lastvisit cookie of his first account he logged with so i must distinguish this cookie with another value like user id but i don`t know the method

Answer (score 0):

Two options: one is to create an associative array of user id and last visit, and store that serialized as the contents of the cookie. Second option is to create a cookie called "last_visit_[user_id]" for each user. The first is probably friendlier add it needs less user cookies.

---

Edit - here is an UNTESTED example. Sorry for any errors, but this should give you the gist.

The critical data is stored in an associataive array of $aLastLogged[UserID] = TimeLastLogged;

```
// This will be the user id of hte current user as set somewhere else.
$userID = 123;


// This will store the time the user last logged on. 0 = not logged on
$LastLoggedOn = 0;

// Read the cookie - allow for errors!
$aLastLogged = false;  // Start with "false" and we'll correct later if is works
// Check if cookie exists
if (isset($_COOKIE['last_logged'])) {
    // Read the cookie contents. The @ hides the errors in case the cookie is corrupted
    $aLastLogged = @unserialize($_COOKIE['last_logged']);
}

// At this point, aLastLogged will be an array, or false if it was not set or failed

if ($aLastLogged) {
    // See if this user has been here before by checking if there is an element in the array
    if (isset($aLastLogged[$userID])) {
        $LastLoggedOn = (int)$aLastLogged[$userID];
        // Note - I cast as "int" to check it's a valid number. You could alos check hte range is valid - just in case someone's been fiddlign with the cookie. Trust no input, ever, including cookies
    }
} else {
    // Create a blank array for the cookie
    $aLastLogged = array();
}


// At this point, you have the time in $LastLoggedOn

// Now update the cookie by creating / updating hte associative element
$aLastLogged[$user_ID] = time();
// Set the cookie; set the time and path and domain as required - the following is for 1 day - you'll want longer.
setcookie('last_logged', serialize($aLastLogged), time() + 86400, '/');
```

Comment: thank you for replay, but i`m a beginner can you give me an example.

Comment: Answer ammended with an example. It's untested - so sorry for any errors - but it should be good enough for you to work out what's going on and to ammend accordingly.